# Convert results to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've got this code:

```
$myarray = @(@(0..3) | foreach {(@(0..$_) | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum})
[array]::indexof($myarray,2)
```

$myarray contains the values 0,1,3,6 so I was hoping `[array]::indexof($myarray,3)` would return the value 2, but it does not. it returns -1.

I'm assuming that the thing I think is an array isn't actually an array, so I'm assuming the thing I'm assigning to `$myarray` needs to get converted to an array somehow, clearly I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of getting values in an array by index number is like this:

```
$myarray[2]
```

Sorry, misunderstood your problem. To get the first occurrence of a value in the array, try this:

```
$myarray.IndexOf([double]3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's not what I want to do. i want to find out which element contains the number '2'. Regardless, I'm not asking how to access the array, I'm asking why the value I'm assigning to $myarray isn't an array (or, at least, doesn't seem to be).

Comment: Well.. it is an array. If you do a $myarray.gettype() you see that it is indeed an array.

Comment: Correct, and my apologies. My logic was wrong elsewhere and hence what i thought was the problem wasn't actually the problem. Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks @ojk, I found a slightly more concise way of doing it: 

$array = @(0..64) | foreach {[int](@(0..$_) | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}   
[array]::indexof($array,2016)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, sorry. Its an array of doubles, not a array of ints. This works (and is actually what I wanted, i.e. the element contiaing 2016):

```
$array = @(0..64) | foreach {[int](@(0..$_) | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}
[array]::indexof($array,2016)
```

Comment: Yep, just found it out myself and updated my first answer :) Glad it's sorted :)